# Can we change speed for specific text?

Tags: javascript, typed.js

From the code below, can we change the typing animation for the second index of strings ('an aspiring developer!') ?

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.home-name-text').forEach(function(el) {
  new Typed(el, {
    strings: ['Ricko Wijaya,', 'an aspiring developer!'],
    loop: true,
    typeSpeed: 100,
    backSpeed: 80,
    startDelay: 100,
    backDelay: 1500,

  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.12"></script>
<span class="home-name-text"></span>
```

Comment: Check out maybe the handler onStringTyped: (arrayPos, self) => {},

This would maybe allow to change the value of typeSpeed between each strings

Comment: *"can we change the typing animation..."* - Do you want the text to fade out instead of a backspace animation ?

Comment: @ths nope. I just want to make the typing speed goes faster for the second animation.

Comment: @Salketer I have no idea how to implement the function as I am new to programming in general.  Here is what I tried

onStringTyped(1, self) => {}  // it shows ',' is expected
onStringTyped(1) => {} // same thing happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the [`preStringTyped`](https://mattboldt.github.io/typed.js/docs/#defaults.preStringTyped) attribute, of the config object that you pass to the `Typed` constructor, to change the *speed* of typing when the index of **the string to be typed** is `1` (that's the index of *"an aspiring developer!"* of your strings array).

The idea is simple, as `preStringTyped` is invoked *"before each string is typed"* you can, at that moment, change/update the `typeSpeed` property of the `Typed` object.

We will be able to do that thanks to the parameters that `preStringTyped` accepts:

- `arrayPos`: the position (index) of the string to be typed (as we saw *"Before each string is typed"* is at the index `1`).
- `self`: is the actual `Typed` object. We can use that parameter to update the `typeSpeed` property.

Basically, what we will do is when the `arrayPos` is `1` we increase the speed (as you requested), otherwise we set it to `100` (as your original code). You can play around that and change the values per your requirements.

To illustrate here's a live demo:

```js
/** the default speed */
const defaultSpeed = 100;

document.querySelectorAll('.home-name-text').forEach(el => new Typed(el, {
  strings: ['Ricko Wijaya,', 'an aspiring developer!'],
  loop: true,
  typeSpeed: defaultSpeed,
  backSpeed: 80,
  startDelay: 100,
  backDelay: 1500,
  /** before each string gets typed, we set the "typeSpeed" to "20" when the string index is "1" otherwise we set it to "100" (the "defaultSpeed" variable) */
  preStringTyped: (arrayPos, self) => self.typeSpeed = arrayPos == 1 ? 20 : defaultSpeed
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.12"></script>

<span class="home-name-text"></span>
```

The above solution works as needed, but personally, I would like to make things even more dynamic. The idea here is to have a separate object that has a *key-value* pairs structure where the *keys* are the indexes of the desired string that is found in the strings array and the *values* are the speeds to use for the string at that index.

Here's a demo to illustrate:

```js
/** 
 * an objkect that hold the speeds for each string index that should have a custom speed
 *    - the key: is an integer that is the index of the desired string in the strings array.
 *    - the value: the custom speed to use for the string at that index
 */
const speedsPerIndex = {
    1: 10,
    2: 300
  },
  /** a default speed to be used initially and when the index of the current string cannot be found in "speedsPerIndex" object */
  defaultSpeed = 100;

document.querySelectorAll('.home-name-text').forEach(el => new Typed(el, {
  strings: ['Will use the default speed (100)', 'Fastest F#@! Boy!', 'Am too slow...'],
  loop: true,
  typeSpeed: defaultSpeed,
  backSpeed: 80,
  startDelay: 100,
  backDelay: 1500,
  /** "typeSpeed" will be dynamic based on the values found in the "speedsPerIndex" object or it will simply default to "defaultSpeed" variable's value */
  preStringTyped: (arrayPos, self) => self.typeSpeed = speedsPerIndex[arrayPos] || defaultSpeed
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.12"></script>

<span class="home-name-text"></span>
```

> You are not limited to change the `typeSpeed` property only, you can change any other attribute you'd need to.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!!! I guess I need to learn about  '?' and '||', it is kind of one-liner if else, right?

Comment: @Kuncung You're welcome! Glad I managed to help.